# Can you set a breakpoint and drop into interactive mode from command line in pycharm 3?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

[image]

I am working on a django project with pycharm 3.4.1 . At the command line shell I have a function that I imported:

```
>>> import v1.views
>>> v1.views.get_data_from_text_file("kk")
```

I have set a breakpoint in the function's code, but when I try to execute at the command line using:

```
>>> v1.views.get_data_from_text_file("kk")
```

It doesn't stop. Is there a way to drop into interactive mode while testing at the command line?

Comment: `pdb.set_trace()`? Not pycharm specific though...

Answer (score 1):

> but when I try to execute at the command line using

It won't stop because PyCharm debugs by importing its own specific python files. Since you're using the command line, the interpreter does not know about *where* you're setting breakpoints.

You can configure your script parameters like so:

[image]

[image]

The red arrow indicates where you should put in your script name, usually is is already filled up for you. The orange one is where you need to place your arguments.

Comment: Games Brainiac, Thanks for looking at this. I clicked Edit configurations but the popup screen has many options. I don't know how to configure them. Any further advice?

Comment: Games Brainiac, Thanks again for looking at this. I'm sorry to be dense, but where can I read about the script and script parameter fields? I don't understand how to use these..

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I finally figured it out: All you have to do is click on the "bug" button while you are working at the python or django console. You will see it says: "Debugger connected." and breakpoints will then work.